# command 'sfdx.force.project.with.manifest.create' not found

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I've installed the latest versions of VScode, the Salesforce CLI, and the VS code Salesforce CLI Extension but when I go to run SFDX: Create Project with Manifest or any SFDX command, I receive an error such as 'command 'sfdx.force.project.with.manifest.create' not found'

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you got it fixed?

Comment: Same here - just started hitting this problem with Summer '19 release

Comment: Try updating your CLI with sfdx update,fix the issue for me